# Can you override a base class's method in an object of an anonymous type in VB.Net?

Tags: java, vb.net

Just that:

Is it possible to create an object of an anonymous type that can override a method of its base class in VB.NET?

E.g., in Java we can do:

```
public class Foo {

    public static Foo bar = new Foo() {
        @Override
        public void doStuff(){
            System.out.println("Look, I'm doing stuff!");
        }
    };

    public void doStuff() {
        //do nothing
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo.bar.doStuff();
    }   
}

//Output:
//Look, I'm doing stuff!
```

Is this possible in VB.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can imitate most of this functionality by declaring the method to be overridden as a delegate function that is a property of the class.

For example:

```
Public Class Foo

    Public ReadOnly doStuff As delDoStuff
    Delegate Sub delDoStuff()
    Private Sub New(del As delDoStuff)
        Me.doStuff = del
    End Sub

    Public Shared bar As New Foo(AddressOf barDoStuff)
    Private Sub barDoStuff
        WL("Look, I'm doing stuff!")
    End Sub 

End Class
```

Anyone have a better way?

Comment: A better way is using the anonymous method syntax – aka. lambdas (but this still uses delegates). In fact, Java’s anonymous classes solve largely the same problem as the concept of closures (and hence lambdas) in other modern programming languages.